# Replacing NA columns with Median in R

Tags: regression, categorical-data

[image]

I keep getting errors with the codes, which would be correct?

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct, but generally you don't want to use `for` loops in R.  Try using `apply`.

**Answer**

```
v <- runif(10000)
v[sample(1000,120)] <- NA
mydata <- as.data.frame(matrix(v,10,100))

for (i in 1:ncol(mydata)){
  mydata[is.na(mydata[,i]), i] <- median(mydata[,1], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

**Apply Solution**

```
v <- runif(10000)
v[sample(1000,120)] <- NA
mydata <- as.data.frame(matrix(v,10,100))

medrep <- function(x){
   x[is.na(x)] <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE) 
   x 
}

dat <- data.frame(apply(mydata, 2, medrep))
```